# Spring and tag mvc resources, can't reach .css, and .js files

Tags: spring-mvc, resources, tags

My application use Spring 3.0.4(this is first version where tag mvc:resources work fine).
The current issue is that my app can not reach .css and .js files from the mapped resources.

Structure test.war:

```
/test -root
   |
   /static-resource
            |
            /css
               |
               /screen.css
            |
            /js
   |
   /WEB-INF
   |
   /index.jsp
```

My test-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/static-resource/"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.web"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

        <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions">
                <list>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
        </bean>

 <bean id="authenticationInterceptor" class="org.util.AuthenticationInterceptor"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="-1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
        <property name="cookieName" value="bovalta_language"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="authenticationInterceptor"/>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
       </list>
   </property>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

In the index.jsp I try access to the resources on two ways with spring url and with JSTL url like below

```
<%-- With JSTL url --%>
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/screen.css"/>" type="text/css"/>
<%-- With Spring url --%>
<spring:url value="/resources" var="resourceUrl"/>
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="${resourceUrl}/css/screen.css" type="text/css" />
```

When I undeploy war file in the Tomcat AS, application work fine without any exception, but Tomcat server can not find my css and js files from resources.
I try to reach css file through url http://localhost:8080/test/resources/css/screen.css
but Tomcat not found it. Any suggestion will be useful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

FYI

For all that would have same problem as I have, I resolved my issue and shared with you:

test-servlet.xml is same without modification as in my above post.

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/static-resource/"/>
```

in the index.jsp page will be:

```
<spring:url value="/resources/css/screen.css" var="resourceUrl"/>
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="${resourceUrl}" type="text/css" />
```

Main problem was in my web.xml because I mapped spring servlet with

```
<url-pattern>/*.htm</url-pattern>
```

instead of that you must mapping only

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

web.xml will look:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks for all!

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so other will see your question has been answered and be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Comment: @plijg whats the difference between / and /*

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and this is how i resolved the issue:
In spring configuration file
Replace

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
With
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

And provide the below path in the JSP to load static contents

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/Mass.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Hope this will help !

Answer (score 0):

### test-servlet.xml

```html
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"></mvc:resources>
```

```css
<link href="<c:url value="../resources/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```